# How to log an API Gateway which is built with Apollo Federation and Apollo Gateway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

Logging looks a hard piece with the apollo graphql. How can we get more insights on the activities happening in a [federated gateway](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/introduction/). I tried [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) but that is good with the REST based perspective. With the graphql perspective how to perform logging.

I saw a package called [apollo-log](https://github.com/shellscape/apollo-log) this works only with the non-federated way and it pollutes the log. What is the ideal way of logging a [federated graphql server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/introduction/)